# Update row only for !empty $_POST values

Tags: php, mysql

This is what my input form looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td class="standard_text_bold" width="25%">First name:</td> 
    <td class="standard_text_bold" width="25%"><input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?echo $Name;?>" <?php if ($Status != "New customer") { echo "disabled"; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="standard_text_bold" width="25%">Last name:</td>  
    <td class="standard_text_bold" width="25%"><input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?echo $Lastname;?>" <?php if ($Status != "New customer") { echo "disabled"; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="standard_text_bold" width="25%">Email:</td>  
    <td class="standard_text_bold" width="25%"><input type="text" name="Email" value="<?echo $Email;?>" <?php if ($Status != "New customer") { echo "disabled"; } ?>></td>
</tr>
```

It's very general, and in a specific case, almost all inputs will be disabled.

I define all my inputs as

```
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
```

And I run an update query

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE data SET
        FirstName = '$FirstName',
        LastName = '$LastName',
        ProductName = '$Productname',
        ProductPriceUSD = '$Productpriceusd',
        ProductPriceEUR = '$Productpriceeur',
        ProductLink = '$Productlink',
        Status = '$Newstatus',
        Modified = now()
    WHERE ID = '$id'
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now I'd like to update ONLY those values that are not empty. Since this is a general query, is it possible to validate variables within the query itself?

I've tried stuff like:

```
if (empty($_POST['LastName'])) {
    $LastName = $row['LastName'];
}
if (!empty($_POST['LastName'])) {
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
}
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `isset($_POST['LastName']);`

Comment: you are setting each value to an empty string in the event that the $_POST[] value is not provided. The SQL statement should be built dynamically to prevent this. Also, don't forget to use mysql_escape_string()! Vulnerable to SQL injection as written.

Comment: Don't use mysql_real_escape_string(), it's deprecated! Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by constructing the query in php to have only the right set statements.

You can also do this in SQL:

```
UPDATE data
    SET FirstName = (case when '$FirstName' = '' then FirstName else '$FirstName' end),
        LastName = (case when '$LastName' = '' then LastName else '$LastName' end),
        ProductName = (case when '$Productname' = '' then ProductName else '$ProductName' end),
        ProductPriceUSD = (case when '$Productpriceusd' = '' then Productpriceusd else '$Productpriceusd' end),
        ProductPriceEUR = (case when '$Productpriceeur' = '' then Productpriceeur else '$Productpriceeur' end),
        ProductLink = (case when '$Productlink' = '' then Productlink else '$Productlink' end),
        Status = (case when '$Newstatus' = '' then Status  else '$NewStatus' end),
        Modified = now()
    WHERE ID = '$id';
```

Comment: This will return the greatest value. What if the ProductPriceUSD is reduced? This will fail to update the price.

Comment: @JmVerastigue . . . You are very right.  I fixed it with the right construct, a `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add  form validation. If the "first name" field is empty text, then you should show an error message and tell the user to fill out the form again.

This covers 999 out of every 1000 forms I've ever created. For the rare case where I have a form made up of only fields... then I add an `<input type="hidden">` field and check for that in the PHP. If it's not there, I know nothing was submitted.

Comment: I may have formulated the questions bad, if you are trying to edit customer info, and customer has a certain status applied to their account, you can't edit all the info, just some of it. I used php to check for status and disable the inputs for the info you can't edit. But I had an error where it would update the fields with blank values, since the inputs were disabled :) The above code with case fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Revise your query to something like this:

```
    $query="UPDATE data SET";


    if (!empty($_POST['FirstName']))
        {
        $query.=' FirstName="' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName'] . '",');
        }
    if (!empty($_POST['LastName']))
        {
        $query.=' LastName="' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName'] . '",');
        }

    $query.="Modified = now() WHERE ID = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

You only append the fields on the query when it's !empty.
Also, you may want to switch to mysqli or PDO as mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: I am planning to make the switch, I'm just finishing a huge project and it would take forever to switch at this point =) But thanks, will definitely check them out